# How to protect my site from session fixation?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-4.0

Currently we are facing a problem regarding session fixation. We do have one site which is secured i.e. Https and there is no authentication for it. It means it has anonymous access.
So, we are facing session fixation problem from hacker. Can someone help and guide on this????

Comment: you have posted 10 question on StackOverflow as for today and have accepted 0 (Zero) answers. Why?

Comment: Ya MikroDel you are right. But it doesnot mean i dont respect those answers. from next I will accept those useful anwers. Thanks.

Comment: thanks ) You can also upvote the questions or answer you like. Or downvote - if something is wrong. If you downvote is helpful also to post some comment - explanation. Upvote - is good without any comment ))

Comment: Here is the answer of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51551957/3649347

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should find the information you need here:

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) - information about Session Fixation

[Session Fixation Vulnerability in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210993/Session-Fixation-vulnerability-in-ASP-NET) - Session Fixation in ASP.NET