# Are Session Fixation Attacks in MVC 5 still an issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, session, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been reading a lot about session fixation attacks and the most popular solutions I've come across are changing the SessionID when user logs in and creating an additional cookie using a GUID to verify the user "belongs" to the SessionID.

My question is this: Isn't it enough to just delete the SessionID cookie (ASP.NET_SessionID) to ensure a new SessionID is generated? 
In MVC 5, when the user logs in an additional encrypted user claims cookies is created (AspNet.ApplicationCookie) which Identity uses to authenticate the user upon each request. The additional "GUID cookie" seems unnecessary.

I’m originally a .NET desktop application developer writing my first MVC app and the learning curve has been a bit steep… although refreshingly enjoyable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I honestly just found out about the Session Fixation attacks but that seems to be the answer to your question. *When authenticating a user, it doesn’t assign a new session ID, making it possible to use an existent session ID*. In my mind this means that the newly generated cookie, might also have the same Session ID. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect my site from session fixation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021431/how-to-protect-my-site-from-session-fixation)

Comment: @I.Am.Me read this article will help you https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1116318/Points-to-Secure-Your-ASP-NET-MVC-Applications

Comment: Here is the solution of session fixation problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51551957/3649347

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain the issue and the solution by using comparisons between desktop and web apps (both in .Net)

When you start your desktop app, the first thing the app shows is a login screen, after which your access to the UI is granted. Now, each time the app's exe is started, it writes the "RunID" to a text file and shows the login screen. The RunID is how the rest of your usage of the app is going to be tracked/correlated.

Assume for a second that the file was on C:\RunID.txt.

An attacker (hacker) can start the exe (without logging in) on Machine1 and copy the contents of C:\RunID.txt to Machine2. Now as soon as you log in on Machine1, the RunID token from Machine1 will also work on Machine2, this is called session fixation.

The ideal way to fix it is to ABANDON the pre-authentication token, and issue a NEW Post-Authentication token. So, you would get a new Token after authentication (or in your case, an additional GUID) which will NOT EXIST on Machine2 and hence provide a level of security in addition to the RunID random token (Session ID)

Let me know if you'd like further explaination, but that is why even in MVC, you should abandon the previous session and create a new session post-auth to avoid session fixation, as a compensating control, you can add a GUID cookie too correspond with the Session ID cookie.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this to avoid that situation:

```
SessionIDManager Manager = new SessionIDManager();

string NewID = Manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
string OldID = Context.Session.SessionID;
bool redirected = false;
bool IsAdded = false;
Manager.SaveSessionID(Context, NewID, out redirected, out IsAdded);
Response.Write("Old SessionId Is : " + OldID);

if (IsAdded)
{
     Response.Write("<br/> New Session ID Is : " + NewID);
}
else
{
     Response.Write("<br/> Session Id did not saved : ");
}
```

Support link:
[Link](https://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/programmatically-changing-the-session-id)

Comment: Link only answer is not encouraged, pls share some context from the link here.